# What is the future value of a growing annuity with different periods for payment growth and monthly payments?

Tags: finance

How can I modify the formula in this [answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/11236/13655) so that the frequency of payment growth is also a variable? For example, instead of payments growing by 2% each year I would like them to grow 2% every two years.